# Avoid Adding Backslash to Curly Brackets when Exporting Latex

Tags: org-export, latex

I want to export an org tree to latex, but whenever I have a command that nests curly brackets, org export will automatically prepend all brackets with a backslash.

For **example**, the tree:

[image]

Exports to (`C-c C-e C-s l l`):

[image]

Instead of:

[image]

**Question:** How do I export the literal latex command I typed without having org-export prepend backslashes as in the example above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [discussion thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2013-06/msg00371.html) is related to my question.
A solution that seems to work for single line Latex commands is to use the in-buffer setting `#+LATEX`.

In the example mentioned in the question, we would have:

[image]

Which correctly exports to:

[image]

Comment: Presumably, your answer has answered your question satisfactorily. If so, you should [accept](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) it.